# Running a tool on the body of your Outlook Emails to validate them before sending them?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, data-validation

By default Outlook checks to make sure you have a subject header on your emails.

If you have some other non-specific external tool you wish to run on the body text of an email before sending it, is there a way to pass as an argument the email body text to the tool and based on the results of said external tool's validation have it prevent you from sending the email?

Comment: There are third-party add-ins for Outlook, such as Outgoing Email Checker, https://www.ablebits.com/docs/outlook-outgoing-email-checker/ , to check attachments, warn of *Reply to all*, etc. *Caveat:* check the safety of *any* add-in before installing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [on-send](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) feature for Outlook add-ins provides a way to handle a message or meeting item, or block users from certain actions, and allows an add-in to set certain properties on send. (The on send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in Office 365 only.)

Here is an article on Configuring and installing the add-in for your reference:
[Outlook-Add-in-On-Send](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send)